# Can I wear tzitzit without having a kipa on my head?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, tzitzis, kippa-yarmulka, tallit-katan

I'm not in a religious school and can't wear my kipa there; but, I would like to wear my tzitzit (tallit katan). Is it permitted to wear tzitzit (tallit katan) without wearing a kipa?

Comment: ... Yes? Tzitzit is a mitzvah, kipa is an entirely separate minhag yisroel. Is there a reason you presume the two are connected?

Comment: why can't you wear your kipa? What country are you in? In the us you have freedom of religion which protects wearing religious articles of clothing which means a us public school may not legally stop you from wearing it

Comment: of course, but its not exactly the community where i would be happy to wear a kipa. thats it

Comment: @EzraHoerster How do you know Kippah is midrabbanan? How do you know one can still do a command (?) if one is not doing a drabannan at the same time? Perhaps it's better to do nothing?

Comment: @DoubleAA i can find sources that state Kippah is just Minhag, not even halacha min'derabbanan. Although the common consensus is that it's halacha.

Comment: There is no requirement to wear a kippah, just to cover the head. Any kind of hat will suffice, like a baseball cap.

Answer (score 5):

Tsitsit is a Mitsva written in the Torah for men wearing some clothes fulfilling conditions of form and composition. Kippa is a custom linked to good character and humility. Both are excellent. As you can place Tefilin without Tsitsit and Brit milah without Tefilin, the lack of Kippa does not prevent the Mitsvat Tsitsit. It is obvious. Maybe I will add later some Chazal quotes.

#### Kippa:

Gemara Kiddushin 31b:

> Rav Huna son of Rav Joshua would not walk four cubits bareheaded, saying: The Shechinah is above my head.

In Gemara this is presented as an great compliment about a great Chacham, as humility.

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 2, 6:

> אָסוּר לֵילֵךְ בְּקוֹמָה זְקוּפָה וְלֹא יֵלֵךְ ד' אַמּוֹת בְּגִלּוּי הָרֹאשׁ: : ‏
>   This is prohibited to walking head up, They do not walk 4 cubits bare-headed.

Nowaday Kippa has a great signification as the famous "ערקבא דמסאנא" (shoe strap; According to Rashi Jews where tying shoelaces differently, not because Mitsva but because modesty, other commentaries says that the color of laces was different). So Bish'at Hashmad may be Yehareg veAl yaavor not least, if no more, than Tsitsit Katan.

Comment: Sisith are a conditional miswah. Wearing sisith are only obligatory when you wear a four cornered garment, and making it a point to wear them is a minhag. For this reason, there are yemenites who don tefillin before sisith as they put the halakha before the minhag.

Comment: @ShamanSTK I added that it is for some type of clothes wearing

Answer (score 1):

According to some, you have to wear a Kippah outside in Public, but according to others less strict you only wear a kippah during prayers. The reason why we wear a kippah is because it reminds us of the Shechina and its bacially showing respect to HaShem. Also it shows that (when out in public) you are Jewish. I am just like you buddy, I wear kippah most of the time at school, and always wear tzitzit.But Boruch HaShem that I am going to yeshiva next year. I pray that you do to.